# AutoMapper Project().To() and sorting a child collection

Tags: c#, automapper, iqueryable

I have an object graph that I'm loading from a database using EF CodeFirst and AutoMapper into DTOs:-

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int FooId { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class FooDto
{
  public IEnumerable<BarDto> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class BarDto
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

My mappings look like:-

```
mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDto>();
```

So far, so good. I can grab the entities from my context and project to the DTO nicely:-

```
var foos = context.Foos.Project().To<FooDto>();
```

What I can't do with this approach, however, is sort the `Bars` by their `SortOrder` inside the IQueryable.

If I try:-

```
mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
  .ForMember(
    x => x.Bars
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bars.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)));
mapper.CreateMap<Bar, BarDto>();
var foos = context.Foos.Project().To<FooDto>();
```

I get an exception:-

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(Type typeIn, Type typeOut)
  ...
```

Seems this is related to https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/159 - though I'm already using a complex type for the child collection. I guess CreateMapExpression doesn't support OrderBy on child collections?

If I'm not using .Project().To() then I can sort the child collection easily:-

```
var model = context.Foos.Select(x => new FooDto()
{
  Bars = x.Bars.OrderBy(y => y.SortOrder)
});
```

but then I have to repeat the mapping wherever I want to use it, defeating the purpose of using AutoMapper.

Curiously:-

1) I can perform other (more complicated?) operations on the child collection and flatten those into my parent DTO no problem:-

```
mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
  .ForMember(
    x => x.AllBarsHaveAName,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
      src.Bars.All(x => x.Name != null)));
```

2) I can `Mapper.Map<FooDto>(foo);` in memory just fine, and it'll sort the bars no problem.

**It's possible to sort the child collection at the IQueryable level while still using .Project().To()?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ended up modifying the AutoMapper source code to support this scenario. Hopefully the proposed fix will be accepted, but in the meantime you can see the details at:-

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/327

Comment: The pull request was accepted and the change is now in automapper 3.

Comment: I'm using AutoMapper 3.3.1, it allows the orderby in the mapper configuration but it doesn't actually order by. the data is not sorted and sql profiler does not show any order by in the generated sql. What am I missing?

Comment: Might be a bug introduced since 3.0, or might be a problem with your config. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a new question, link to it here, and I'll take a look?

Comment: I found my problem, I had several Map configurations and I had added the order by on one ViewModel map configuration but my test was running against a different ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if sorting the Bars inside the Queryable during mapping is the best place to do this?  Wouldn't placing the sort in the map mean that it sorts at inappropriate times?

For example, what if you just wanted to know if the Bars collection contained 1 item? Calling 
`FooDto.Bars.Any()` would still result in a sort in the database.

Perhaps it would be better to have another property in the FooDTO (ignored in the mapping) that looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<BarDto> SortedBars
    {
        get
        {
            if (Bars == null)
                return null;

            return Bars.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you could potentially utilize the "AfterMap" method on the mapping configuration stuff of AutoMapper to do your sorting?

Comment: Colin: I'm unlikely to pull the entire DTO just to see if FooDto.Bars.Any() - it's a specific query for a specific view.

Comment: Richard B: I looked at AfterMap, and it'll do the job (as would Colin's "SortedBars" property) after a fashion, but having profiled I'd prefer that the sort takes place on the database as it does when I do .Select(x => new FooDto...)

Comment: I thought that when you access the Bars property - such as in the Bars.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder) call - then the sort does take place in the database. At least it should on first load if the property is marked as virtual and lazy loading is enabled?

Comment: FooDto isn't a lazy-loaded entity. It's a data transfer object that I'm trying to map my entities onto - hence wanting to perform the sort during the map, so that when I call Project().To<FooDto>() the sort gets performed on the database.

Comment: I would have thought that automapper would map a reference of the ICollection<Bar> to the IEnumerable<BarDto> but would not populate it immediately. Then through the magic of deferred execution the ICollection<Bar> would be lazy loaded with the OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder) filter, which would then be passed to the Entity Framework to work out the sql to run....but I'm no expert. I must set up a test and go try to understand this....

Comment: AutoMapper isn't doing anything magic with EF. All it's doing is providing the Foo/FooDto and Bar/BarDto mappings which get used in the Select. Try the non-AutoMapper case - var model = foos.Select(...) - you'll see that the child collection gets eager-loaded. Even if there *were* lazy-loading magic going on, I know I need the entire DTO so I'd want the child entities eager-loaded anyway.

Comment: I can see that the foos.Select will eagerly load the data - there is a specific call to the Foo.Bars property in the projection. I was suggesting that you could get the same data using lazy-loading. But that would result in multiple calls to the database and I guess I hadn't understood what you really wanted is to load the entire graph of all Foos and all Bars in one query. It's a bit like the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7522784/150342. But you want automapper's QueryableExtensions to do the work instead of how it's done there. Right?