# How to include navigation properties eagerly for child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern

Say my object graph looks like:

```
User
 => Friends
   => Clicks
     => Urls
```

So when I load a User, I also want to eagirly load the navigation property Friends.  And I want the friend object to eagirly load Clicks and so on.

Using the code I have now I can only do this for 1 level:

```
public User GetUserById(int userId)
{
  return Get(x => x.Id == userId, includeProperties: "Friends").FirstOrDeafult();
}
```

Is this possible?

- I'm using MVC 4.1
- I'm currently using the repository pattern based on http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this repository implementation is just splitting the `includeProperties` parameter by comma (`includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }`) and then calls

```
query = query.Include(includeProperty);
```

for each element in the result array of the split. For your example you can use a dotted path then:

```
return Get(x => x.Id == userId, includeProperties: "Friends.Clicks.Urls")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It will load all entities on the path from the root `User` entity to the last navigation property `Urls`.

If you had another navigation property in `User` - say `Profile` - and you would want to eagerly load that as well, it seems that this syntax is supported then:

```
return Get(x => x.Id == userId, includeProperties: "Profile,Friends.Clicks.Urls")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What about setting the orderby for the child collections when they load? is this possible?

Comment: @user1361315: It's not directly possible, there are only some workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522784/ef-4-1-code-first-how-to-order-navigation-properties-when-using-include-and-or